# Does the electron's electric field strength differ when bounded to a nucleus from the strength in a free state?

Tags: electrostatics

Since in any material the nucleus is surrounded by electrons some of the electron's electric field does interact with the other electrons from the same atom and with the electrons from the surrounding atoms. Even on the surface of an uncharged body there are a lot of electrons.

Adding electrons we observe an electric field. Is it possible to define a density of electrons on the surface shell and to calculate the increase of the electric field's strength when the body becomes charged (as electrons are added)? Has this been calculated and does the electron's electric field strength differ when bound to a nucleus from the strength in a free state?

Comment: Are you talking about the free electron model? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model

Comment: @The Quantum Physicist From your link I follow to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screening_effect. That it seems to be.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Could you make it an answer, please?

Comment: I'll expand on the comment I made on your next question: you've misunderstood what is happening with the screening effect. It is no more or less than the usual superposition of electric fields. There is no change in the charge of anything nor any change in field the contribution due to any selected particle. If you go forward thinking that there is then you will only make one mistake after another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're talking about is a part of the free electron theory in solid state physics. I believe you have to consult a solid state physics book, like [Kittel's](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP000803.html) or [Aschcroft's](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0030839939).

A good start can be in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model) at the [Screening effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screening_effect).

Comment: The reason for my question was the following question [Is the magnetic dipole moment in charged particles the more survivable property than the electric charge?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235080/is-the-magnetic-dipole-moment-in-charged-particles-the-more-survivable-property)

Comment: @TheQ I think it is importnat to read Holger's question (and his previous one and his next one) carefully. He's imaging that there is some fundamental change in the electron and if you allow him to think that you've confirmed that he's going to keep making mistakes.

Comment: @dmckee Please feel free to extend my answer. I think if he gets into details with this he'll understand it.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist If you don't mind please read my elaboration [About the distribution of electrons magnetic dipole moments in atoms](https://www.academia.edu/18391675/About_the_distribution_of_electrons_magnetic_dipole_moments_in_atoms_Part_1). It fits the observations but it is a new interpretation.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler I'm so sorry. I'm too busy to look into details about this.

Comment: @The Quantum Physicist. Thanks for the honest answer.